# How many temporary files can I open simultaneously in C program?

Tags: c, temporary-files, temporary

I have one question of temporary file open in C program.

I know there is FOPEN_MAX in stdio.h. As far as I know, FOPEN_MAX is the number of files(not temporary) can be opened simultaneously in C program. But, If I make temporary file using 'tmpfile()', does the number of temporary files included in FOPEN_MAX ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are basically saying that you believe a temporary file is not a real file, but something else. Why do you think that?

Comment: OK I know what you mean. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not written explicitly, but it seems the limitation is the same, no matter if file is temporary or not.

https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tmpfile&category=3&russian=5

See error code for `tmpfile()`:

```
EMFILE
{FOPEN_MAX} streams are currently open in the calling process.
```